# How to import nodes and their translations from a csv using Feeds?

Tags: 7, feeds, i18n-l10n, importing-exporting

Is there a way to provide the original and translated values of the title and the body in a csv for example, and the Feeds module to produce the translated nodes automatically (and synced with the original nodes - [tnid])?

I have tried using "[Feeds: Entity Translation](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_et)" but with no success.I have set the fields to be translatable but i don't see the translation fields available in the node-importer.

Any advice on the best practice on this?

Should i better go with a [Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) implementation?
All ideas/implementations welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: I use to work with feeds before, but I think that migrate is a better way to import content into drupal than feeds.

Comment: Do you have to use feeds? Why not use a [node import/export module](https://www.drupal.org/search/site/%22node%22%20import?f%5B0%5D=&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=&f%5B3%5D=drupal_core%3A103&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&f%5B5%5D=ss_meta_type%3Amodule&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage+desc) (or write your own if you can't find anything that does what you want)?

Answer (score 0):

While Feeds:entity translation should be awesome when finished you can try this [Solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69763/using-feeds-to-import-multiple-languages)

> I created two feed imports.
>       I forced the language field for each one.
>       Two separated nodes were created for each content (one in each language) but it didn't links the translations.
>       So I used a SQL query to finish the job, it's based on the feeds uuid :

I think he meant: based on guid not uuid

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Asnwers. I would recommend you to elaborate on your answer by describing in more detail your recommended solution.