# Multiple language node import with Feeds

Tags: commerce, feeds, i18n-l10n

I am using [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds/) to import a very huge CSV file with products to my [Drupal Commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce/) site. My site must be in two languages and it appears that [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds/) hasn't support for this. How can I import nodes in multiple languages with [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a fantastic [Solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69763/using-feeds-to-import-multiple-languages) not so long ago that addressed something similar.

I believe that the best thing to to would to be to split each node into two nodes (one in Language A, one in Language B) and import each one in a separate feeds import, and then use the SQL query in the above solution to link the translation. This way, each node can contain otherwise identical information about the same item, in its own language, and simply be displayed based upon which translation the user/viewer would prefer.

Let us know how you go with the SQL script and if you have any issues that you need help with!

Comment: Waw! This solution works for me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this but it looks like it should do what you need it to do - [Feeds: Entity Translation](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_et).

> This module adds support for importing data through Feeds into
>   translatable fields handled by Entity Translation.
>
> The module exposes fields that are translatable into all enabled
>   languages, enabling the creation of translations of entities when
>   importing.

It's still in dev, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this without needing SQL queries. Feeds now had multilingual support for fields. Make sure you have a current version. Newer than a year ago, because of https://www.drupal.org/node/1183440

You can create two feeds, one for each language. In the processor you should set a common unique identifier as unique in both feeds. Also you can, for each field, set the language variant for that field and feed.

Make sure that the fields you want to translate have entity transltion enabled though!