# Feed import save empty value in multilingual site

Tags: 7, feeds, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site and I am using the feed module to import content. My site has two languages:

English and Arabic.

When my excel files have English content, it imports properly.

But if excel file having Arabic content, it imports and shows in view page but in edit page it not displaying.

Comment: Are you using the latest version, `7.x-2.0-beta2` ?

Comment: feed module version = "7.x-2.0-beta1"

Comment: You should [update](https://www.drupal.org/node/583948/release) to the latest version **YES! Feeds finally supports translation of fields using [Entity translation!](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_et) Also new in this release is support for updating existing items only and for the CSV parser an option is added to convert the character encoding of the CSV file to UTF-8**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Feeds: Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_et)

> This module adds support for importing data through Feeds into
>   translatable fields handled by Entity Translation.
>
> The module exposes fields that are translatable into all enabled
>   languages, enabling the creation of translations of entities when
>   importing.

Another fantastic [Solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69763/using-feeds-to-import-multiple-languages)

Import from two xml files (on for each language), my empiric solution :

- I created two feed imports.
- I forced the language field for each one.
- Two separated nodes were created for each content (one in each
  language) but it didn't links the translations.
- So I used a SQL query to finish the job, it's based on the feeds uuid